# Desabilitar paginação e exibir todos os registros ao começar a buscar no datatable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatable

Estou usando *serverside* no *datatable* JQuery. PHP mais JQuery. Os dados são puxados do banco de dados. Especifiquei que apareça 9 registros em cada pagina (da paginação). Mas preciso que quando começar a buscar alguma coisa quero que a paginação deixe de existir e liste 'todos' os registros. E quando deixar de buscar, volte ao normal com somente 9 registros por pagina e paginação. 
Sei que o *datatable* é flexível e tem os comandos da API pra mudar isso, o problema e que não sei qual é.

Alguma ajuda?

example:

```
 <script>

 table = $(#table).datatable({
"processing": true, 
"serverSide": true,
"order": [], 

"ajax": {
    "url": "<?php echo site_url('Locacao/ajax_list')?>",
    "type": "POST",
},
"pageLength": "9",
"bPaginate": true
})
</script>
```

php metodh:

```
  class Locacao extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct(){
         $parente = parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('Locacao_model','locacao');
    }
  public function ajax_list()
  {
  $list = $this->locacao->get_datatables();
  $data = array();
  $no = $_POST['start'];

  foreach ($list as $locacao) {

    $no++;
    $row = array();

    $row[] = $locacao->id;
    $row[] = $locacao->name;
    $row[] = $locacao->date;
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  $output = array(
    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
    "recordsTotal" => $this->locacao->count_all(),
    "recordsFiltered" => $this->locacao->count_filtered(),
    "data" => $data,
        );

  echo json_encode($output);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONSEGUI RESOLVER, SEGUE CODIGO:

```
  //ASSIM QUE COMEÇAR A BUSCAR, DIGITAR ALGUMA COISA
  $('.dataTables_filter input').on( 'keyup', function () {
   //PEGA O VALOR DIGITADO
   var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
   //VE SE TEM ALGUM VALOR NO VALOR DIGITADO
  if(value != null && value != " " && value != false){
    //SE TIVER ALGUM VALOR MUDA A QUANTIDADE DE ITEMS EXIBIDO NA PAGINA
    $table.page.len( 10 ).draw();
   // SE NAO TIVER ALGUM VALOR, VOLTA AO NORMAL A QUANTIDADE DE ITEMS 
  }else{
    $table.page.len( 1 ).draw();
  }
  } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar o e evento preXhr da busca ou diretamente no campo da  ou na api (_fnFilterCustom se não me engano)

Antes de iniciar a busca, usa a api para remover a paginação (bPaginate) quando tiver algum texto na busca e adicionar novamente quando não tiver texto

https://datatables.net/reference/event/preXhr

https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: tentei desta forma mas sem sucesso ate agora:

Comment: var oSettings = $table.fnSettings();
      oSettings.bPaginate = false;
      $table.draw();

Comment: $table.on('search.dt', function() {
                var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
              
               alert(value);

            });